# Error Unknown Http Status 0, Angular and Express API deployed on IIS

Tags: angular, api, express, iis, frontend

I have an Angular Front-end and an Express API deployed on IIS in a remote desktop. When I run it in the remote desktop, everything works correctly but when I try to run it on my real pc, I got this error :

[Http Error Status 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcddX.png)

I precise that I'm using a VPN and I have access to the front-end on my pc but http request seems to not work

Comment: A status code of 0 generally means there was no response, and can occur for various reasons. The server will never return a status of 0 as this is not a valid HTTP status code. based on your description, some form of firewall seems the most likely culprit.

Comment: @samwu ok. I will see what I can do about that. Thanks you

Comment: Has your problem been solved?